# R same amplitude classification

Tags: r

I want to classify a variable in class with the same amplitude. 
I haven't found an easy way to do that... is there a function?
At this point it work with :

```
n<-13
r<-(max(data[,3])-min(data[,3]))/ (n-1)
bornes<-seq(from=min(data[,3]),to=max(data[,3]), by=r)


sel<-data[,3] < min(bornes)
data$classe[sel]<-1
sel<-data[,3] > max(bornes)
data$classe[sel]<-13


for(i in 2:length(bornes)-1){
  b1<-bornes[i-1]
  b2<-bornes[i]

 sel<-data[,3] > b1 & data[,3] < b2
 data$classe[sel]<-i
}
```

It work but it's ugly ... there is a better way?
Thank's

E

Comment: I can't quite tell, but isn't this a long way around creating a frequency table for a histogram?   Take look at `hist` and the output object it creates.

Comment: Thank's Carl, of course hist !! it's more elegant with hist(data[,3], bornes)! And if I want add a column wiht the classification from breaking point? A great idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `cut`.

```
n_breaks <- 13
data <- rnorm(100)
categories <- cut(data, seq(min(data), max(data), length.out=n_breaks), include.lowest=T)
(data.frame(data,categories))
```

Hope this helps.